# Run a program via systemd service ponting to shell script

Tags: shell-script, systemd

I want to run a program (obs) at a certain times, for that I wanted to write a systemd service file which points to a shell script, that I would then have executed by a timer.

I've run the file and it does execute the script...but but for some reason doesn't execute the program.

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starting Yoga recording on OBS

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "yo working" >> /home/user/1.txt

/usr/bin/obs --minimize-to-tray --startrecording

echo "or is it?" >> /home/user/2.txt
```

The strings do get written to the text files and `script.sh` does work when executed via terminal, so I'm sure the problem is with the service file

I'm on an Arch distro btw if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect OBS is a GUI application.  `systemd` runs scripts great, but GUI applications take a few tricks.

First, use the `--user` bus.  This means OBS will run as *you*, and not as root.  Other than the obvious security benefits, running on the user-bus lets your service inherit your users environment including which `$DISPLAY` you are using and where your `$XAUTHORITY` is.  It also means that running bash will load your personal `.bashrc` which wouldn't happen on the system bus.  To do that, move these `systemd` units from `/etc/systemd/system/` to `~/.config/systemd/user/`.

> I want to run a program (obs) at a certain times

Use a systemd timer for that:

```
#~/.config/systemd/user/obs.timer
[Unit]
Description=Timer for OBS

[Timer]
# Run obs.service every 2 hours
OnCalendar=*-*-* 00,02,04,06,08,10,12,14,16,18,20,22:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

That will trigger `obs.service` every two hours.  Then your `obs.service` can remain the same:

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/obs.service
[Unit]
Description=Starting Yoga recording on OBS

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

To cause this to launch on startup:

```
$ systemctl --user enable obs.timer
$ systemctl --user start obs.timer
```

The timer will trigger your service, so you don't have to explicitly start or enable your service.

If you want the service to run NOW, then you can always start it yourself:

```
$ systemctl --user start obs.service
```

Comment: I checked `home/user/.config` but there was no systemd directory there. Arch wiki also suggests to place files there, so am I supposed to make that directory? btw thanks a lot, I knew I'd have to write a timer but I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @GAD3R I never said he was wrong, I even said Arch Wiki agrees with him...I did not find such a directory so was asking if I'm supposed to make that directory myself

Comment: @GAD3R yeah I think it systemctl doesn't check the directory that I created, I get `Failed to start obs.service: Unit obs.service not found.`

Comment: If `~/.config/systemd/user/` doesn't exist, you can create it and `systemd` will find it.   I see you have `Unit obs.service not found`.  Did you use `systemctl start` or `systemctl --user start`.  The `--user` will make `systemd` look in the `systemd/user` directories.  Also, when working on the `--user` bus, do **not** use `sudo`.  You need to run as yourself.

Comment: Oh wait is it explicitly systemd/user ? I thought it was to replaced by the current username

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, it works now